# Updating a TextView in an Activity from a Service in Android?

Tags: android, service, textview

I have a TextView in an Activity which I wish to update from a service. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). An intent should be fired from a service and `TextView.setText()` called in the `onReceive()` method of the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: After days of reading multiple SO posts and various tutorials, I came back to this post- and can say with complete confidence- that this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I would suggest creating some kind of interface that the service feeds updates to. The activity will implement this interface and set itself as a 'listener' on the service (removing itself in `onDestroy`).

Comment: Che is correct. Look at Broadcast and BroadcastReceiver - in your broadcast you can send intents with actions and extras that you can receive in your main activity, interpret and update your UI with.